# Create a link pointing to #

Tags: 8, navigation

I am trying to make a link pointing to # but am unable to find a method that works.

The output i would like to see is

```
<a href="#">Example</a>
```

I have tried a few variations of the following without success.

```
$url = Url::fromUserInput('#');
$link_item = Link::fromTextAndUrl(t('Example'), $url);
return $link_item->toRenderable();
```

I have also tried using  ::fromUri etc and am unable to find a method that produces tehd esired output, please help.

Comment: See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/144992/how-do-i-create-a-link. It might help

Comment: Sorry, i cannot see any reference to linking to a # or a fragment on that page.

Answer (score 8):

It's probably not possible to attach an empty fragment. See this code in  `UrlGenerator::generateFromRoute()`:

```
if (isset($options['fragment'])) {
  if (($fragment = trim($options['fragment'])) != '') {
    $fragment = '#' . $fragment;
  }
}
```

If the fragment is empty it is ignored and no '#' shows up. This doesn't change if you provide the fragment in `Url::fromUserInput()`, because the fragment is transfered to the options and later processed by the same or similar code.

So you have to provide an anchor in the fragment:

```
$url = Url::fromUserInput('#anchor1');
```

or

```
$url = Url::fromRoute('<current>', [], ['fragment' => 'anchor2']);
```

As alternative option you can place a link with an empty fragment

```
<a href="#">{{ examplevariable }}</a>
```

either in a twig template or in an inline template in php.

Answer (score 0):

The following code:

```
$link = \Drupal\Core\Link::fromTextAndUrl(
          t('Example'),
          \Drupal\Core\Url::fromUserInput('#', ['fragment' => '#'])
        )->toString();`
```

will return:

> `<a href="##">Example</a>`

---

Here is the example to return a custom path:

```
\Drupal\Core\Link::fromTextAndUrl(t('Example'), \Drupal\Core\Url::fromUri('base:/some/path'))->toString();
```

which returns:

> `<a href="/some/path">Example</a>`