# How to generate a link as 'href="#"'?

Tags: 8, theming

In my theme, I have to output a toggle link like this:

```
<a class="hl__link-tag hl__link-tag--with-arrow js-show-more-text-link" href="#" title="Click to show more / less text" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="showMoreText{{ paragraph.id() }}"><span class="hl__link-tag__toggle-text">Show Less</span><span>Show More</span></a>
```

Its not a real field or anything like that. Is there a way I can use `link` or `path` functions to generate this output instead? I am guessing since the title has two spans in it that I cannot, but lets assume there were no spans, I'd like to know if this is possible.

I tried:

```
{{ link('Show More', 'internal:#') }}
```

and

```
{{ link('Show More', '#') }}
```

The first one creates an empty href, which does not work. The second throws a fatal error.

Comment: see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/231491/create-a-link-pointing-to

Comment: Why not using built-in Twig functions? Macros, include, embed,... should do the same

Comment: You can't. You have to use preprocessor and inline template.

Comment: If you really must use an `a` element better use `href="javascript:void(0)"`. Related discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/q/134845/2199525

Comment: At best use `<button>{{ 'Show more'|t }}</button>`.

Answer (score 2):

You could just type it into the template and dont have to do anything clever or twig based? e.g.

```
<a href="#">Show more</a>
```

The core html.html.twig quite happily does this for the #main-content link:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21templates%21html.html.twig/8.2.x

Comment: That is what I am already doing, I just don't like it very much.

Comment: `<a href="#">{{ 'Show more'|t }}</a>`