# Empty link creation

Tags: 8

Is there a way to create an empty link in D8? What I want specifically is

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">Link</a>
```

`Url::fromUserInput('#', ['fragment' => '#'])` creates an anchor tag with `##` link.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a link pointing to #](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/231491/create-a-link-pointing-to)

Comment: Might not be. The solution in the link creates a `#` link. I want a `javascript: void(0)` linked anchor tag.

Comment: Because of what you tried I thought it might be. Either way, I expect the answer will be the same: use an inline or twig template to do this. The Url class - from a cursory glance at the source - I don't think will generate a javascript url.

Comment: A possible way out might be like this - 
`$nolink_url = Url::fromUserInput('#', ['fragment' => '#', 'attributes' => ['onclick' => 'return false']]);`
Though this would not put a javascript: void(0) in place, but will stop the jump to the top which was my actual requirement. :)