# Add a custom link to the contextual menu of every block

Tags: 8, blocks, navigation

I want to add a custom contextual link on the top of every block. there are many answers available on the site but these answers are about adding a contextual link to a specific block. and I need to add a contextual link which appears in the contextual menu of every block available in the site. I have tried this function.

```php
function MYMODULE_contextual_links_view_alter(&$element, &$items) {
  if (isset($element['#element']['#block'])) {
    $element['#links']['animation'] = array(
      'title' => 'change animation',
    );
  }
}
```

I didn't get what I want.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of the link element is wrong.

This is a sample from the documentation of the [`Link`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21Link.php/class/Link/8.4.x) render element.

```php
$build['examples_link'] = [
  '#title' => $this->t('Examples'),
  '#type' => 'link',
  '#url' => Url::fromRoute('examples.description')
];
```

[How do I create a link?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/144992/how-do-i-create-a-link) has several answers with methods to produce the link.