# How do I convert special characters into html in twig

Tags: 8, theming

I have some list items in drupal 8 which created by `item_list` template.I am sending some `<a>` tagged data to the `item_list` template. My idea was to get the output as `<a href="/this-is-new.html">This is new page</a>`.

But it returns the output as `<li>&lt;a href="/this-is-new.html"&gt;This is new page&lt;/a&gt;</li>`.

I need to print this in a twig template. But with the output I had it renders as a string in the template not as a html anchor tag. I needed to view a link to another page in template. But all I am getting is a string with the `<a href="/this-is-new.html">This is new page</a>`. What should I do?

Answer (score 6):

**NOTE:** this should be avoided as it is considered bad practice as mentioned in the comments, leaving here as an **example to avoided**

Inside your twig template try this

```
  {{ var|raw }}
```

where `var` is the variable being printed.

For more information [here](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/raw.html)

Comment: Using the `|raw` filter should be avoided for security reasons. For a better method to get the raw value see [How do I get the raw field value in a template?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/228388/how-do-i-get-the-raw-field-value-in-a-template/228393#228393)

Comment: Sorry for the down vote, but I consider using the `|raw` filter bad practice. You event mentioned it in your comment `{# var won't be escaped #}`. But I don't want you to delete this answer, It's good for others to learn about avoiding this security pitfall.

Comment: @NoSssweat This won't work for me because it only escapes the outer element. As an example with my code it will only escape `<li>` tag but not the string inside. I need to convert the string inside. This output is coming from `item_list` by auto generating the lists from Drupal. Because of that I can't grab the inside string in the `<li>` tag.

Comment: @NoSssweat twig documentation does not mention anywhere that its not secure.

Comment: It’s not, inherently, but anything that a user could have provided must be escaped for XSS. That’s where security becomes a concern

Comment: so what makes @NoSssweat's solution linked above more secure. I mean they are both raw/non processed inputs ... or am I mistaken ?

Comment: Everything inside `{{ }}` is automatically escaped for xss, unless a filter (like `raw`) is used See https://www.drupal.org/node/2296163 for more info

Comment: @GiorgosK you cannot trust user input, you need to escape what user's put into fields/forms.  **Using `|raw` turns off Twig's auto escaping mechanism**, while on the answer that I liked to the auto escaping mechanism is still on. [Watch this to see why escaping is crucial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gwUEjgbs02w&feature=youtu.be&t=1h58m37s).

Comment: @NoSssweat yes I understand the reasoning behind escaping but I did not know the inner working of you solution and that it was actually being escaped (thought it was raw) ... thanks for the link very informative

Answer (score 3):

Try using convert_encoding('UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES') twig filter. For example {{ item|convert_encoding('UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES')}}.

Comment: This don't work for me :(

Comment: This no longer works in Drupal 9, which throws the warning: 
Notice: iconv(): Wrong charset, conversion from `HTML-ENTITIES' to `UTF-8' is not allowed in twig_convert_encoding() (line 1000 of vendor/twig/twig/src/Extension/CoreExtension.php).

Comment: Just found out this doesn't work in Drupal 9 as well. What is the alternative?

Comment: Somebody created a module to replace this functionality in Drupal 9: https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_htmlspecialchars_decode

Answer (score 3):

To send html markup to a template use a `#markup` render element

```
$variables['link'] = [
  '#markup' => '<a href="/this-is-new.html">This is new page</a>',
];
```

so that the html tags are not escaped when you output the variable in twig:

```
{{ link }}
```

The link here is only an example. There are better ways to build links, see [How do I create a link?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/144992/how-do-i-create-a-link)

Answer (score 3):

There is a module to use the old convert_encoding('UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES') for D9
https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_htmlspecialchars_decode

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/138009)

Answer (score 2):

> But it returns the output as `<li>&lt;a href="/this-is-new.html"&gt;This is new page&lt;/a&gt;</li>`.

The reason for this, is because Twig is auto escaping your HTML. List only allows list related HTML tags, like `<li>`.

> I have some list items in drupal 8
>
> My idea was to get the output as `<a href="/this-is-new.html">This is new page</a>`

Don't use List as your field type, instead use Link and set it to **unlimited**.

[image]

---

Now when you add a new node:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can make use `Markup class` which defines an object that passes safe strings through the render system.

1.) You first need to create a TwigExtension.php class inside a module and define a function which will actually return a formatted string.

2.) Use that function inside any of your twig files to render formatted strings.

3.) Do Rebuild the cache, using `Drush cr`.

-> **Create a module_name.services.yml file under modules/module_name:**

```
services:
  module_name.twig.TwigExtension:
    class: Drupal\module_name\TwigExtension
    tags:
      - {name: twig.extension}
```

-> **Create a TwigExtension.php under modules/module_name/src/TwigExtension.php :**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\module_name;

use Drupal\Core\Render\Markup;

/**
 * Class DefaultService.
 *
 * @package Drupal\module_name
 */
class TwigExtension extends \Twig_Extension {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   * This function must return the name of the extension. It must be unique.
   */
  public function getName() {
    return 'block_display';
  }

  /**
   * In this function we can declare the extension function
   */
  public function getFunctions() {
    return array(
      new \Twig_SimpleFunction('render_string', array($this, 'render_string'), array('is_safe' => array('html'))),
    );
  }

  /**
   * Function to decode html special chars
   */
  public function render_string($string) {
    $render_string = Markup::create($string);
    return $render_string;
  }
```

-> **Insert twig function inside your twig file: **

```
{% set str = render_string('<a href="/this-is-new.html">This is new page</a>') %}
....
....
{{ str }}
```

Hope, this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a special case for title field:

```
{# Template field--node--title--my-node-bundle.html.twig #}

{%
  set classes = [
  'field',
  'field--name-' ~ field_name|clean_class,
  'field--type-' ~ field_type|clean_class,
  'field--label-' ~ label_display,
]
%}
<span{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
  {%- for item in items -%}
    {# transform title from "inline_template" render element into "markup", to avoid escaping #}
    {% set content = item.content|merge({'#type': 'markup', '#markup': item.content['#context']['value']}) %}
    {{ content }}
  {%- endfor -%}
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can render links with `item_list`. Here's an example how to from the book module:

```
  public function bookRender() {
    $book_list = [];
    foreach ($this->bookManager->getAllBooks() as $book) {
      $book_list[] = Link::fromTextAndUrl($book['title'], $book['url']);
    }
    return [
      '#theme' => 'item_list',
      '#items' => $book_list,
      '#cache' => [
        'tags' => $this->entityTypeManager()->getDefinition('node')->getListCacheTags(),
      ],
    ];
  }
```

The key is to not pass it as markup, but as a renderable array/object.