# How to add custom class in custom module?

Tags: 8

I am not able to add custom class in custom module, I need to add class "ajax-link" in the anchor link to make it ajax based page load  .

```
function hook_node_view(array &$build, \Drupal\node\Entity\Node 
$node, \Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, 
 $view_mode) {

 if ($display->getComponent('prevnext_next')) {
$build['prevnext_next'] = [
  '#theme' => 'prevnext',
  '#direction' => 'next',
  '#text' => t('Next'),
  '#nid' => $previous_next['next'],
  '#attributes' => array(
  'class' => array(
  'ajax-link' 
      ),
    ),
  '#url' => Url::fromUserInput('/node/' . $previous_next['next']."?an=left")->toString(),
  '#void' => empty($previous_next['next']),
];
 }
   }
```

What am I doing wrong in the code ?

I want to create link something like this:

```
<a class="ajax-link" href="node/nid?an=left">Next</a>
```

Comment: What does your prevnext theme / template code look like?

Comment: `theme_prevnext` isn't making use of `#attributes`, it's pretty much that simple

Comment: I am not getting you @clive , so what should i use instead of #attributes to add class.

Comment: What @Clive means is that theme function doesn't use an "attributes" variable so putting that key in there has no effect. If all you want is an A tag you could use a #type link instead. See. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/187780/13727

Answer (score 0):

you can try code :

```
  $url = Url::fromRoute('entity.node.canonical', ['node' => $previous_next['next'],'an'=>'left']);
  $url->setOptions([
      'attributes' => [
          'class' => ['ajax-link custom-class']
      ],
  ]);

  $build['prevnext_next'] = [
      '#type' => 'link',
      '#title' => t('Next'),
      '#url' =>  $url,
  ];
```