# How to pass values to content creation page to set default values in form elements?

Tags: 8, forms, domain-access

### Introduction *(not necessarily needed to be able to answer the question)*

I use [Domain Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) module to be able to manage different sites from one Drupal installation and a single shared database. I enabled Domain Content submodule that provides a content administration page for each subdomain.
Instead of having all contents of all domains displayed at `/admin/content`, this allows to display all contents of a given domain at `/admin/content/domain-content/mydomain`.

### What I'd like to do

I'd like to prefill a form element in ***Create Article*** page according to a given domain.

So I plan to add a ***Add content*** button at `/admin/content/domain-content/mydomain`, and pass the parameter `mydomain` from here until, for example, ***Create Article*** page.

Then I'll be able to prefill (tick) the right domain checkbox in the ***Create Article*** page according the passed argument.

### My question

How to pass parameters between the given admin pages to be able to prefill a form in ***Create Article*** page?

Answer (score 2):

#### Altering the form

You should implement the [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter). Then, read the parameters like this:

```
$name = \Drupal::request()->request->get('country'); // from param
```

Then alter the *form elements*, rewriting the `#defatult_value` conditionally, like this:

```
$form['field_country']'#default_value'] = 'my domain specific default';
```

In the case of a checkbox widget, the `#default_value` is an array ([source](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1100170)):

$form['countries']['#default_value'] = [1, 3];

#### Passing parameters in general

If your parameters are simple strings, like `country: denmark`, you could use GET parameters. This answer has the sample code:

[How do I create a link?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/144992/how-do-i-create-a-link)

#### Passing parameters through the '/node/add' route

This is a special route, it is not so simple.

**Method 1: Implementing a subtheme**

If you are using the default admin theme ('seven') you would have to create a subtheme, and overwrite this hook, so that your custom parameters are passed:

```
   /**
     * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for list of available node type templates.
     */
    function seven_preprocess_node_add_list(&$variables) {
      if (!empty($variables['content'])) {
        /** @var \Drupal\node\NodeTypeInterface $type */
        foreach ($variables['content'] as $type) {
          $variables['types'][$type->id()]['label'] = $type->label();
          $variables['types'][$type->id()]['url'] = \Drupal::url('node.add', ['node_type' => $type->id()]);
        }
      }
    }
```

**Method 2: Overwriting the twig template**

The links are ultimately rendered by the  `core/themes/seven/templates/node-add-list.html.twig` template. To overwrite this output, you would: 
 - Implement a `hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK`
 - Copy the `node-add-list.html.twig` to `node-add-list--custom.html.twig` and implement your custom changes here.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK()
 */
function hook_theme_suggestions_node_add_list(array $variables) {
  $suggestions = array();
  $suggestions[] = 'node_add_list__custom';
  return $suggestions;
}
```

Comment: Since I need to pass dynamic arguments, I edited my question to be more precise.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea. I'd like to mention that there is an intermediate page between `/admin/content/domain-content/mydomain` and **_Create Article_** page. How to pass the param through the intermediate page, which is `/node/add`, until **_Create Article_** page?

Comment: Just added the fun part: "Passing parameters through the '/node/add' route", and then reordered the sections.