# How to apply suggested theme hook using hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK?

Tags: 8, theming

Following [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/268944/85453),  I'm trying to override `core/themes/seven/templates/node-add-list.html.twig` using [hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK/8.5.x).

So, I added the following function in `modules/custom/domain_filter/domain_filter.module`

```
function domain_filter_theme_suggestions_node_add_list(array $variables) {
  $suggestions = [];
  $suggestions[] = 'node_add_list__' . 'custom';
  return $suggestions;
}
```

I created the custom twig file in my module: `modules/custom/domain_filter/templates/node-add-list--custom.html.twig`

The suggestion appear well in theme debug but it's not applied (the `x` is in front of `node-add-list.html.twig`):

```
<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'node_add_list' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * node-add-list--custom.html.twig
   x node-add-list.html.twig
-->
```

How to apply `node-add-list--custom.html.twig`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found [a paragraph in the documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/howtos/using-template-tplphp-files-in-your-own-module#drupal8). When using modules, we need to register the template using `HOOK_theme()`. So, I added the following function in `modules/custom/domain_filter/domain_filter.module`

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function domain_filter_theme() {
  return [
    'node_add_list__custom' => [
      'base hook' => 'node_add_list',
    ],
  ];
}
```

Then my custom template `modules/custom/domain_filter/templates/node-add-list--custom.html.twig` is now applied.

Answer (score 1):

you need add to your theme

```
themes/yourtheme/templates/node-add-list--custom.html.twig
```

Comment: Thanks, this can be useful when you create a subtheme or a new theme but I just want to use a module.